# Why do we need arithmetical operations instead of teaching arithmetic based on the successor function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, arithmetic, education, math-history

Since we can construct the set of natural numbers off of the peano axioms with the operations of addition, subtraction, multiplication and division following, why do we even need 4 arithmetical operations? Since the successor function is "modelled" off of counting as we know it as babies, it is quite intuitive for many people. Why then don't we just teach all of arithmetic based off a axiomatic, intuitive, and quite "primitive" notion of the successor function, and why do we specifically need 4 arithmetic operators? (Specifically where even the basic notion of addition of natural numbers is hard to put into words, without a lengthy exposition which a young person would have a hard time understanding).

Comment: The less you know, the harder life is.  Are you going to start every calculation with an appeal to the Peano axioms?  It'll take you a long time to bake a cake.

Comment: I don't really get your question? You are saying we should teach little children about set theory? A similar thing has been tried in France in the sixties and it went horribly wrong... It was called bourbakisme.

Comment: @MushuNrek No, I am not suggesting a constructivist way of teaching arithmetic, just curious as to why across the world we teach four operations, where three of them (subtraction, division, and multiplication) aren't basic in any sense. If a student asked you why we add the way we do, asking for a proof, how would you answer their question? (obviously without giving a full exposition of peano arithmetic)

Comment: I am not exactly sure how you would explain addition to children, but as far as I am concerned, the first thing children are told is to take one object at a time and count upwards, what is exactly the successor function. And the four operation they are taught are very useful in life which is the principle aim of mathematics. And I think that addition and substraction are present everywhere. The same thing holds for multipliction which just a structured way for additions. Perhaps I would agree with you that division is not very natural at first sight. It is the most artificial of the four.

Comment: @Mushu Nrek: You don't need to pull in all of set theory to explain the basic ideas of Peano's postulates. They are really just saying "we create numbers by counting, and there's enough of them to satisfy all our counting needs". (referencing your mentioning about "bourbakisme".)

Comment: @The_Sympathizer Since bourbakisme is not very well known, there is not a lot to find about, but for the general idea : https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourbakisme

Comment: I'd like to mention that addition and multiplication are not always related to each other via a successor function in every ring or field. They are related via the distributive law but not necessarily a successor function. So in more general structures, it is good to think of addition and multiplication as being separate operations without boiling down to the same function.

Comment: @Favst : Sure, but here we're talking about specifically the natural numbers, at least that's how I understood this question.

Comment: Because we do not learn through definitions (Peano's axiom for sum) but through recipes (procedures).

Comment: @MushuNrek I was a child in a tiny village school in the 1960s with teachers barely worthy of the name. We were taught mathematics by the technique known as "program learning", a technique followed by Stroud's "Engineering Mathematics". One of those books taught fractions, one taught decimals, one taught geometry, and one taught set theory. And it was clear as crystal. At age 8 I understood the mechanisms of set theory (its operations, its concepts and the basic properties) and in my mind there was nothing simpler or prettier. For this to have failed in France means the teachers were failures

Comment: @PrimeMover I guess it really comes down to the individual child, but for the most part children understand addition if it's more concrete.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is, in effect, what the Peano definitions of the arithmetic operations do: they build them from the successor function - e.g. the recursive definition for addition is

$$a + 0 := a$$
(base case)

$$a + S(b) := S(a + b)$$
(recursion case)

It becomes clearer if one notes that effectively almost by definition,

$$b = (\underbrace{S \circ S \circ S \cdots S}_{b})(0)$$

so that

$$a + b = a + (\underbrace{S \circ S \circ S \cdots S}_{b})(0) = (\underbrace{S \circ S \circ S \cdots S}_{b})(a)$$

which says that "$a$ plus $b$ works by adding $b$ single things one at a time to $a$", and if you want to show a child, show hir stacking little blocks of hir favorite type together on top of a given tower of blocks, one block at a time, and then the remaining tower has a number of blocks that equals the sum of the two amounts in the preceding towers.

The reason we *have* the operation of addition is because it very quickly gets awful to say "two, then one more, then one more, then one more, then one more", and much better to say "two plus four". And better, because it *generalizes* beyond the simple case of natural numbers.

Comment: So, the only reason of having an addition operator in arithmetic would be it serves as a kind of a shorthand way of denoting repeated succession then, just like multiplication? Is it just a matter of convention?

Comment: @lmn32 : Well no, that's not the _only_ reason - because the larger intuitive concept is, since numbers are supposed to be a way to express measurements of the size of things, to translate into numbers what happens when you take two measurable amounts of "stuff" together as a single amount of such "stuff" and give the number corresponding to that. But what it seemed you were asking about was how/why we should have addition _from the Peano perspective_ of the numbers as being built up one-by-one.